# show multiple product photos on WooCommerce single page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, gallery

I want to show multiple product photos instead of thumbnails. I want my product page to look like this page: https://arhoj.com/products/sip-cup-pink-mink

This is how my code look in file: product-image.php

```
<div class="images">

<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $image_title    = esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $data_caption   = esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $image_caption  = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt;
        $image_link     = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
        $image          = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), array(
            'title' => $image_title,
            'alt'   => $image_title
            ) );
        $attachment_count = count( $product->get_gallery_image_ids() );
        if ( $attachment_count > 0 ) {
            $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
        } else {
            $gallery = '';
        }
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-caption="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_caption, $data_caption, $image ), $post->ID );
    } else {
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" />', wc_placeholder_img_src(), __( 'Placeholder', 'xclean' ) ), $post->ID );
    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>
```

Comment: what is the problem ? edit your question to give more details.

Comment: I don't know how to show all photos from product gallery on single product page. Thanks.